# Iterate throughout div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a button, I need to get a status i.e. to check weather its male or female, below is my code.

```
<!-- GENDER BUTTON -->
<div class="btn-group gender_guest" tabindex="0">
    <a class="btn active btn-default btn-success gender" onclick="genderClicked(this,'female${status.index}')" id="male${status.index}">Male</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default gender" onclick="genderClicked(this,'male${status.index}')" id="female${status.index}">Female</a>
</div>
```

My script

```
function genderClicked(clickedObj, id) {

    $('#' + id).removeClass("active");
    $('#' + id).removeClass("btn-success");

    $(clickedObj).addClass("active");
    $(clickedObj).addClass("btn-success");

}
```

This script works fine,its purpose is to just change color.I need another method to know which gender is selected...

Inside my JavaScript page I need to set in to a variable what is the gender, my onclick and id is used to pass the value to change the color when it gets clicked.So without touching that I need to set the value to that variable.

Comment: Could you make this into a fiddle or JSBin so we can see the script too?

Comment: @JohannesJander i added my script too

Comment: $('#' + id).val(); Will give you the value of the gender.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, use the class selector to add an event.

I commented the JS, to explain what it does.

```js
$('.gender').on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent that the anchor is triggered
  e.preventDefault();
  // remove the classes from a links
  $('.gender_guest a').removeClass('active btn-success');
  // add the classes to the clicked one
  $(this).addClass('active btn-success');

  // get the gender */
  var gender = $(this).attr('id');
  // returns male.... or female...
});
```

```css
/* only for demonstration */
.active{ border: 2px solid blue }
.btn-success { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- GENDER BUTTON -->
<div class="btn-group gender_guest" tabindex="0">
    <a class="btn active btn-default btn-success gender" id="male${status.index}">Male</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default gender" id="female${status.index}">Female</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, inline js is a debugging/maintenance horror!!! @OP Stop spreading that already.

Answer (score 0):

```
function genderClicked(clickedObj, id) {
  ..
  var gender = "male";
  if( id == "female${status.index}" ){
     gender = "female";
  }
  console.log(gender);
}
```